# PYTHON: __init__ method does not create attributes?

Tags: python, class, init

I'm working with Tkinter and I'm trying to create an attribute called wordlist for a main object that belongs to the Main1 class.

This is the Main1 class:

```
class Main1(Instructions):
    def __init__(self, master, wordlist):
        super(Main1,self).__init__(master)
        self.wordlist = self.readwords()
        self.textbox.insert(0.0,self.wordlist)
    def create_wdgts(self):

        mainlbl = Label(self,text="Tänk på ett ord!")
        mainlbl.grid(row=0,column=2)

        self.textbox = Text(self, width = 50, height = 5, wrap = WORD)
        self.textbox.grid(column=2,row=1)

        self.backbttn = Button(self,text="Tillbaka")
        self.backbttn["command"] = self.back
        self.backbttn.grid(column=5,row=0)

        self.pointentry = Entry(self)
        self.pointentry.grid(column=2, row=2)
        self.pointlbl = Label(self,text = "Poäng:")
        self.pointlbl.grid(column = 1, row= 2)
        self.pointbttn = Button(self, text="skicka poäng")
        self.pointbttn.grid(row= 2, column = 3)
        self.pointbttn["command"]= self.pointhndlr()

        self.crrctlbl = Label(self, text = "Rätt ord:")
        self.crrctlbl.grid(column = 1, row = 3)
        self.crrctentry = Entry(self)
        self.crrctentry.grid(column = 2, row= 3)
        self.crrctbttn = Button(self, text="skicka rätt ord")
        self.crrctbttn.grid(row= 3, column = 3)

        self.yesbttn = Button(self, text="Ja")
        self.yesbttn.grid(row = 4, column=4)

        self.nobttn = Button(self, text = "Nej")
        self.nobttn.grid(row=4, column=5)

    def readwords(self):
        """Returns list with all words in words.txt"""
        file = codecs.open("words.txt","r","utf8")
        wordlist = []
        for word in file:
            wordlist.append(word.strip())
        return wordlist

    def guess(self):
        self.guesstemp = random.choice(wordlist)
        self.textbox.insert(0.0,"Ange poäng för ordet '"+guesstemp+"': ")

    def pointhndlr(self):
        pointtemp = self.pointentry.get()
        self.pointentry.delete(0)
        self.wordlist = remvwords(self.wordlist,self.guesstemp,self.pointtemp,self.guesslist,self.pointlist)
```

I hope I don't need to post more of the program as this is already a lot of code. Anyway, I get an error message saying that my Main1 object has no wordlist attribute. Why? I created it in the **init** method!

Grateful for all help.

Sahand

EDIT:  The error is traced back to the last line, where I try to change the value of self.wordlist.
The error message is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/SahandZarrinkoub/Documents/graphics.py", line 294, in main1
    main1.guess()
  File "/Users/SahandZarrinkoub/Documents/graphics.py", line 364, in guess
    self.textbox.insert(0.0,"Ange poäng för ordet '"+guesstemp+"': ")
NameError: global name 'guesstemp' is not defined
```

Comment: Where do you get that error?

Comment: When is "pointhndlr" called? Rather, when is create_wdgts called?

Comment: Show how you create the object. Most likely your `__init__` does not run. And why are you passing a `wordlist` parameter to `__init__` that you ignore?

Comment: My **guess** is that calling the base constructor will invoke create_wdgts, which will call self.pointhndlr. Note that when you assign `self.pointbttn["command"] = self.pointhndlr()`, you're not making that button *call* that method when you click it, instead you're actually calling that method as part of that assignment, assigning whatever it returns (which seems to be nothing, aka `None`), to the command.

Comment: def main1(self):
        self.pack_forget()
        main1 = Main1(root, readwords())
        main1.create()
        main1.guess()

This function in an object from another class creates the object.

Comment: Instead of pasting a whole bunch of mostly-irrelevant code and leaving out lots of other code, please strip your code down to a minimal, complete example that demonstrates the problem. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for more guidance.

Comment: "EDIT: The error is traced back to the last line, where I try to change the value of self.wordlist." _What_ error? Please post the exception and traceback, and the relevant code, instead of just saying that there's some error of some kind.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lasse, I made an error by forgetting to not include the parentheses after self.pointhndlr, which caused the constructor to run pointhndlr, which caused the program to crash since wordlist had not yet been assigned. Thanks a lot!

Comment: posted my comment as an answer with slightly more detail

Comment: Read your error, it complains about `guesstemp` not existing, not what you said the problem was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason here is that this:

```
super(Main1,self).__init__(master)
```

will in turn call this:

```
def create_wdgts(self):
```

which will in turn do this:

```
self.pointbttn["command"]= self.pointhndlr()
```

This does *not* assign the *function* `self.pointhndlr` to `self.pointbttn["command"]`, instead it calls `self.pointhndlr`, and assigns the result to `self.pointbttn["command"]`.

The solution: remove the parenthesis:

```
self.pointbttn["command"]= self.pointhndlr
```

Answer (score -2):

The way you call super.init is wrong.

You used:

```
super(Main1,self).__init__(master)
```

You should use:

```
super(Main1,self).__init__(self, master)
```

The way you called it, the object you are creating **is not** initialized as an `Instructions` instance. Instead, the `master` object gets re-initialized or re-cast as an `Instructions` instance.

Comment: The call to `super` is perfectly right (assuming `Instruction.__init__()` takes `master`as argument of course). Please check your facts.

Comment: If you're lucky, this "fix" will just raise a `TypeError` when you try to construct a `Main1` because you passed one too many arguments. Otherwise, it'll construct a `Main1` whose parent window is itself, which will lead to disastrous and painful-to-debug problems.